# pandas DataFrame to list of dicts using to_json()

Tags: python, json, string, pandas, datetime

So, i'm reading a xlsx file with pandas, then parsing the datetime (excel's a float)

Then I need to parse it into Json, and I'm running into some problems.

STEP 1 (Before parsing with to_json())

```
df = pandas.read_excel('test.xlsx', names=['date', 'value', 'source'])
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %Y.%f')
print(df)
```

the return is

```
        date  value                            source
0 2012-05-22      1              xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
1 2012-05-25      1                     xxxxxxxxxxxxx
2 2012-05-30      1  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
3 2012-06-01      1                        xxxxxxxxxx
4 2012-06-08      1                 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Everything seems fine, then I got o to_json

```
payload = df.to_json()
```

And the return is

```
{"date":{"0":1337644800000,"1":1337904000000,"2":1338336000000,"3":1338508800000,"4":1339113600000},"value":{"0":1,"1":1,"2":1,"3":1,"4":1},"source":{"0":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","1":"xxxxxxxxxx","2":"xxxxxxxxxxx","3":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","4":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}}
```

So what am I doing wrong? Am I missing args on to_json()? Halp pls :c

I needed it to be like this:

```
[{"date":"2012-05-22","value":1,"source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{"date":"2012-05-25","value":1,"source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{"date":"2012-05-30","value":1,"source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{"date":"2012-06-01","value":1,"source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"},
{"date":"2012-06-08","value":1,"source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]
```

Comment: Looks like your datetime objects are being coerced to unix timestamps. Is that an issue? What do you want it as? Strings? Then just do `df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %Y.%f').astype(str)` and proceed as usual.

Comment: edited! sorry :p

Comment: Also you can use `df.to_json(orient='records')` to get the desired output.

Comment: @GabrielFernandes Yup, was already mentioned in the answer I'd written. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a couple of fixes—

1. Convert your date column to string, because as it currently is, your datetime column is being coerced to Unix integer timestamps. Alternatively, use the `date_format` argument with `to_json` as the other answer suggests.
2. Change the orient when you save to json; specify `orient='records'`.

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%b %d %Y.%f').astype(str)
payload = df.to_json(orient='records')
```

```
print(payload)
'[{"date":"2012-05-22","source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","value":1},{"date":"2012-05-25","source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","value":1},{"date":"2012-05-30","source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","value":1},{"date":"2012-06-01","source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","value":1},{"date":"2012-06-08","source":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","value":1}]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Although if you convert to string (as mentioned in other questions and comments) you can get the format you want, you may not need to. Check out the **[`to_json()` parameter `date_format`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)**. I believe you want `.to_json(..., date_format='iso')`.

As per the documentation for the `date_format` parameter:

> For orient=’table’, the default is ‘iso’. For all other orients, the default is ‘epoch’.

Comment: that will result in dates in the format like this `2012-05-22T00:00:00.000Z`, which is not OP's desired output.